# Wire transfer problem

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, singapore, swift, turkey

I have wire transferred my funds through a Turkish bank using SWIFT code and intermediary bank JP Morgan Chase bank in the US to my account in Singapore. It is already 8 months and I have yet to receive my funds. Please advise what to do next. My banks in Singapore stated they cannot locate my funds and my sender stated that they had sent my money by providing proofs to me that my money had been sent — MT103 and MT199. My sender and my banks in Singapore stated they cannot do anything. So where are my funds now and what must I do next?

Comment: What did JPM Chase say when you asked them?

Comment: Sorry, but the chain is not clear to me. The receiving bank account is in Singapore. In what country is the sending bank account? Then there is turkish bank in Switzerland ? (swiss code) and a US bank involved? Can you make it more clear, please. And did you really send this 8 months ago?

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify... you start "_I have wire transferred my funds_" suggesting **you** initiated the transaction, then say "_my sender stated that they had sent my money_". Do you mean "_my sending bank_" or was "_my sender_" another person, who was sending money to you? If it _was_ another person that sent / was-meant-to-send you the money, then <obligatory-anti-scam> is it someone you know in any "real" way, or just a "_stranger from the internet_"™ who's asked you to do something in return for the payment?